# Add-on for limiting by paragraph and words/characters?

Tags: add-on

Are there any add-ons for EE 2 that can handle limiting both by paragraph and number of words (or characters)? With just paragraph I might end up with too much text if the paragraph is long and with just words or characters I end up with several paragraphs if they're shorter. Ideally, I don't want to use multiple add-ons.

Answer (score 2):

I find https://github.com/EllisLab/Word-Limit by EllisLab to be very effective in this scenario.

Another favourite is Hacksaw http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/hacksaw

There are quite a few other options as well on Devot-ee http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=word+limit&collection=addons&addon_version_support=ee2

Comment: Thanks, will check those out. I don't think Word Limit will work since it has no way of ensuring it sticks to just one paragraph. There used to be an HTML Limiter or something such for EE 1 that allowed specifying both paragraph and number of words.

Comment: I think Hacksaw is probably the better bet here